# Convert collection to JSon and send with mqtt

Tags: java, gson

I'm reading a csv file and save the content in a collection of my datamodel. Now i want to convert the collection with Google Gson into Json and then send as bytes over mqtt.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String csvFile = "/Users/xxx/Desktop/file.csv";
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    List<Datamodel> _listmodel = new ArrayList<Datamodel>();
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    String line = null;


    try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile))) 
    {

        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            lines.add(line);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i<lines.size() ;i++)
        {

            String[] data = lines.get(i).split(";",-1);
            _listmodel.add(new Datamodel(data[0],data[1],data[2],data[3],data[4])); 
        }

    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String json = gson.toJson(lines);
    System.out.println("json = " + json);

    //Test- Convert back to List not working??????

    Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Datamodel>>(){}.getType();
    List<Datamodel> neueliste = gson.fromJson(json, type);

}
```

I'm getting a Exception on the Convert back to List. Can someone help me and maybe tell me if my plan to send this Json string as bytes to a android client would work with mqtt.
Is there a possibility to send the csv file directly with mqtt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first cast it to **object** then cast it to **list**.

```
   Object object = gson.fromJson(json, Object.class);
   List<Datamodel> neueliste = (List<Datamodel>) object;
```